# How can I get the current signed user info after the token has been receive in Magento 2 Rest API

Tags: magento, magento2

After looking at the Magento 2 REST token-base Authentication System. upon Successful login, I received an authorization token but I don't know how to get the current customer details with the token so I can know the current user.

Here is the instruction to get te token I followed.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: what details are you interesting for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use these methods to receive information about yourself (i guess you logged in as customer)

Retrieve default billing address for the given customerId:

```
GET http://Magento-2-0/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/billingAddress
```

Retrieve default shipping address for the given customerId:

```
GET http://Magento-2-0/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me/shippingAddress
```

To retrieve common customer info you should use:

```
GET http://Magento-2-0/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me
```

response should be something like:

```
    {
  "id": 0,
  "groupId": 0,
  "defaultBilling": "string",
  "defaultShipping": "string",
  "confirmation": "string",
  "createdAt": "string",
  "updatedAt": "string",
  "createdIn": "string",
  "dob": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "middlename": "string",
  "prefix": "string",
  "suffix": "string",
  "gender": 0,
  "storeId": 0,
  "taxvat": "string",
  "websiteId": 0,
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "customerId": 0,
      "region": {
        "regionCode": "string",
        "region": "string",
        "regionId": 0,
        "extensionAttributes": {}
      },
      "regionId": 0,
      "countryId": "string",
      "street": [
        "string"
      ],
      "company": "string",
      "telephone": "string",
      "fax": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "firstname": "string",
      "lastname": "string",
      "middlename": "string",
      "prefix": "string",
      "suffix": "string",
      "vatId": "string",
      "defaultShipping": true,
      "defaultBilling": true,
      "extensionAttributes": {},
      "customAttributes": [
        {
          "attributeCode": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "disableAutoGroupChange": 0,
  "extensionAttributes": {},
  "customAttributes": [
    {
      "attributeCode": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each call should have header "Authorization":"Bearer token"

Comment: Yes, you are right but then, I have no access to the customerId because what was returned to me after the successful login was just the Bearer token.

Comment: 1) Why do you need customer id?
2) receive customer id, you should use login on behalf on admin

Comment: look into my answer , i have added update. You can receive customer id, by /V1/customers/me

Comment: Thanks, that work, but the reason why I need the customer info was because I need to show the current signed in customer info upon a successful sign.